# Query for pages a user didnt visite

Tags: mysql

Maybe its easy, but I can't find a solution...

I have a table storing a row everytime a user visits a webpage (both are integer-values)

```
user_id  I  page_id
1        I  1
2        I  1
1        I  2
1        I  3
(...)
```

I want to get a list of all pages a user didnt visit yet, ordered by how often other users visted them.

I started with

```
SELECT page_id, COUNT(*) as anz FROM clicks WHERE user_id!=XXXX GROUP BY page_id ORDER BY anz DESC
```

But this doesnt work, because it also shows pages the user visited if another user visited it already.

What ist a good query if I want only the pages the user didnt visit, ordered by the count other users visited it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is an aggregation with some additional logic:

```
SELECT page_id, sum(user_id <> XXXX) as anz
FROM clicks
GROUP BY page_id
HAVING sum(user_id = XXXX) = 0
ORDER BY anz DESC;
```

The `sum()` counts the number of other users that have viewed the page.  MySQL treats booleans as integers, with true being `1` and false being `0`.  The `having` clause only allows pages where the given user has never seen the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.page_id, COUNT(t2.page_id) as anz 
FROM clicks as t1
LEFT JOIN clicks as t2 on t1.page_id=t2.page_id
WHERE t1.page_id not in(SELECT DISTINCT page_id FROM clicks WHERE user_id=XXXX) 
GROUP BY t2.page_id 
ORDER BY anz DESC
```

Comment: This works, but the query from Gordon is much faster - so I will use his. But thanks a lot, your answer also works.